# Trying to sort by the number of vowels, the program does not sort at all

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

My intention was to count he number of vowels in each string in each index, add that number to an array, and then sort both the arrays using bubble sort. (this is for a class, and we are not allowed to use arrays.sort or any of the arrays.methods.) It is not sorting whatsoever and I'm unsure as to why.

```
public static String[] sortByVowels(String[] a) {
    String[] copy = a.clone();

    int[] numVowels = new int[copy.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < copy[i].length(); j++) {
            int count = 0;
            char ch = copy[i].charAt(j);
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            count++;
            }
            numVowels[i] = count;
        }
    }
    for (int c = 0; c < copy.length - 1; c++) {
        for(int d = 0; d < copy.length - c - 1; d++) {
            if (numVowels[d] > numVowels[d+1]) {
                int swapInt = numVowels[d];
                numVowels[d] = numVowels[d+1];
                numVowels[d+1] = swapInt;
                
                String swapString = copy[d];
                copy[d] = copy[d+1];
                copy[d+1] = swapString;
            }
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: You are counting the vowels wrong, inside the inner char loop. Each char resets your counter to 0 or 1.

Comment: Akarnokd! You've solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akarnokd in the comments solved it. My counter *int count = 0;* was inside the inner char loop when it should've been outside in the first for loop. Thank you!